# How to attach static IP to a virtual machine using gcloud?

Tags: networking, gcloud

Trying to attach existing reserved IP address to a new virtual machine using gcloud

it's easy to do in the console, can't find a way how to do it using gcloud

Answer (score 0):

See:
[link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#assign_new_instance)

```
gcloud compute instances create [INSTANCE_NAME] --address [IP_ADDRESS]
```